# Bash script to control another bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

We have a script at work that we use for a thing :) . When we call it with the command config12 we have to choose 1, after that we must enter the word all, press 0 or 1 (whether we want it to activate something or deactivate it) and after it executes press 0. I tried to automate this, it does what it has to but it doesn't exits properly remaining stuck in a loop because at the end the 0 is probably not received.
Do you have any idea why it may not work? Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "1 -->> Deactivate"
echo "2 -->> Activate"
read opti

case $opti in

1)
config12<<!
1
all
1
0
!
;;

2)
config12<<!
1
all
0
0
!
;;

esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your script by means of a sample `config12` of the following form:

```
while read x
   do echo $x
done
```

Everything has been read and the whole processing finished successfully. Perhaps `config12` is the script that gets stuck expecting some more data?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I took a look at the config12 script and right where it gets stuck, when it should take the 0 and exit there are some rsh commands on 7 servers.